# how to convert a number to a date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a `type 2` number in my `Oracle` database such as `20180201`

I would like to convert it to a proper date, but the naive `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(mydate))` does not work

What is the proper syntax?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(20180201),'YYYYMMDD')`

Comment: well done buddy. that was quite simple indeed

Comment: To understand why your attempt failed and Kaushik Nayak's worked, you need to understand date format models. Oracle accepts "strings as dates" in many different formats, so `to_date()` must be given the format model. If you don't give it, then Oracle uses a session default, stored in the parameter `nls_date_format`; if yours is not exactly `'yyyymmdd'`, your attempt will fail. In any case, it is always a best practice to give the format model explicitly (even if your session `nls_date_format` parameter *was*, in fact, `'yyyymmdd'`).

Comment: ...and more importantly, if you are indeed storing dates as numbers in DB, **avoid** it. Dates should always be stored in tables as datatypes `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`( for millisecond precision).